# My bash script is not showing console window when executed

Tags: bash, debian, xfce

I made a bash script which takes an input form the user:

```
#!/bin/bash
# mnthere - mounts virtual box share in current working directory
echo Enter the source share name:
readline NAME
sudo -- mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 $NAME $0
```

But when I double-click it, nothing happens. It executes in background probably failing with an error. I need to configure it to show that window, how do I do that? Is that related to XFCE4 desktop environment I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the launcher, you can check at the beginning of the script whether it is being executed in a terminal. If it isn't, open a terminal and restart the script there. At the top of the script:

```
if [ ! -t 1 ]; then
    args=''
    for arg in "$@"; do
        args="$args \"${arg//\"/\\\"}\""
    done
    xfce4-terminal -e "$0 $args"
    exit 0
fi
```

Then if there is any terminal output to display to the user, add this to the bottom:

```
read -n1 -u1 -rp 'Press any key to close this window.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch an xterm running your script instead of just running your script and add a `read` command for instance to stop the output and be able to read.

`gnome-terminal -x your_script`

Comment: In other words, double clicking the bash file just does never spawn the console window?

Comment: Right, it will execute but it won't have an Xwindow container.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the launcher (right-click, select Properties, then click on the edit button), one of the options will be a check-box "Run in terminal".

Check that and your script will now run in a terminal.

Comment: There's no such option in my xfce. Or maybe I am just not sure what do you refer to as "launcher".

Comment: how do you "click on it" - did you make a launcher icon on the desktop, or from within Thunar or some other file browser.  If the latter, I don't think there's any way to do what i said (except right-click, Send To -> Desktop to make a desktop icon).  If the former, then it's both easy and obvious.

Comment: but my specific instructions were mistakenly for a panel icon.  For a desktop icon, it's right-click, select Properties, and then select the Launcher tab.

Comment: It's not here. Are you talking about xfce or Ubuntu? [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/olyU8.png)

Comment: xfce.  v4.12.1 on debian sid, to be precise.  other versions may vary.